# How can i make a multiple color gradient to the right but with a glow effect to bottom?

Tags: css

so im trying to make a gradient like this one but with other colors:
[image]

So, im kinda new to css and i don't know how to make this glow effect bellow the gradient, thanks!

Comment: use 2 gradients on top each others ;) If you want a good answer instead comments or downvote / closed question , share the code you have to describe and demonstrate your issue. ;) read again https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you include what code you have already?  Also, what "glow" effect are you referring to? Do you mean how the colors fade to/towards black along the bottom edge.

Answer (score 2):

A background image can consist of more than one image - the first image in the list overriding those that come afterwards.

Using gradient images this snippet puts a transparent to a sort of dark gray from top to bottom image over a left to right gradient of colors.

Obviously this is just a start which will require you to play around with the parameters and the colors to get the effect you want.

```css
div {
  height: 10vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0, #404040 40%), linear-gradient(to right, cyan, magenta, yellow);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```